# Upadate roster name on server side and send it to client

Tags: xmpp

I'm new to XMPP and I'm trying to understand if this is possible. 
I have a small xmpp server where an user logins and has 2 friends with the names "A" and "B". 
At a certain point in time I want to change(update) the friends names(not necessary in the same time) to "C" and "D" , on the server side, and send the new names to client to update them as well, but I don't know if this is possible. Something similar to Presence stanzas when you can change the status (Online, Busy, etc..)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. The server just needs to send an IQ stanza to all entity's resources. Something like this:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" to="user1@localhost/57779eb8dd91498fa462046c502e581f" type="set" id="e603d81c6d284735abf9555b2cc9796e"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"><item jid="user2@localhost" name="Some nick name" subscription="both"></item></query></iq>
```